# Different between "return db.SaveChangesAsync()" and "return 0"

Tags: c#, enums, implicit-conversion

I wanna get a status after appending new message to database. I defined an enumeration (type `int`), but the method gave me 2 error messages when I called `return await db.SaveChangesAsync();`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'xxx.Models.MessageStatus' to 'int'.

and

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'xxx.Models.MessageStatus'.

My test code:

```
enum MessageStatus
{
   Success,
   Failure
}

private async Task<MessageStatus> AddMessage()
{
   using (var db = new VinaChanelDbContext())
   {
      try
      {
          //do stuff...

          await db.SaveChangesAsync();
          return MessageStatus.Success; /* or return 0; */
       }
       catch { return 1; /* or return MessageStatus.Failure; */ }
   }
}
```

[MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync) says:

> SaveChangesAsync() will return `Task<int>`

So, my question is: Why doesn't `AddMessage` method accept

```
/* implicit conversion to MessageStatus.Success or MessageStatus.Failure */
return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion beterrn `MessageStatus` and `int`:

> Each enum type defines a distinct type; **an explicit enumeration conversion (§6.2.2) is required to convert between an enum type and an integral type**, or between two enum types.
>
> *from C# spec - 14.5 Enum values and operations*

Because of that you can't directly return `int` from method that's defined to return `MessageStatus`. For the same reason you can't return `Task<int>` from method declared to return `Task<MessageStatus>`.

You can cast `int` to `MessageStatus` before returning, but you can't return it directly.

```
return (MessageStatus)(await db.SaveChangesAsync());
```

However, that might not be a godd idea, because you don't know what `int` value will `SaveChangesAsync` return, and your enum might not match it exactly.